# How to create one query instead two or more separated queries from one collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a collection with following structure:

```
{
    "_id" : "Pd2fl7xcT3iWEmpAafv4DA",
    "slot" : 1,
    "stat" : [
        {
            "unitStat" : "5"
            "value" : 13
        },
        {
                "unitStat" : "18",
                "value" : 1.96
        },
        {
                "unitStat" : "28",
                "value" : 1373
        },
        {
                "unitStat" : "41",
                "roll" : 2,
                "value" : 69
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get 5 sorted objects (by any `unitStat` type) for every slot.

In that moment, I can perform 6 calls to db, but it isn't a good idea.
I tried to use aggregation, but I can perform it only for one slot:

```
db.collection.aggregate( 
    {
        `$match`: {
            slot: 1,
            secondaryStat: {
                `$elemMatch`: {
                    unitStat:'5'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        `$unwind`: `'$secondaryStat'`
    },
    {
        `$match`: {
            'secondaryStat.unitStat' : '5'
        }
    },
    {
        `$sort`: {
            'secondaryStat.value': -1
        }
    },
    {
        `$limit`: 5
    }
)
```

Can I find, for example top 5 sorted objects from 6 different slots?

Answer (score 0):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
        {
                $unwind:"$stat"
        },
        {
                $match:{
                        "stat.unitStat":"5"
                }
        },
        {
                $sort:{
                        "slot":1,
                        "stat.value":1
                }
        },
        {
                $group:{
                        "_id":"$slot",
                        "slot":{
                                $first:"$slot"
                        },
                        "stat":{
                                $push:"$stat"
                        }
                }
        },
        {
                $project:{
                        "_id":0,
                        "slot":1,
                        "stat":{
                                $slice:["$stat",0,5]
                        }
                }
        }
]).pretty()
```

**Aggregation stages details:**

- Stage I: Unwind the stat array
- Stage II: Filter unitStat for any specified value. "5" in this case.
- Stage III: Sort the data in ascending order on the basis of slot and
  stat.value
- Stage IV: Group back the data on the basis of slot and push all filtered stat into an array with name 'stat'
- Stage V: Slice the stat array with the specified length. 5 in this
  case.

Comment: Thx for answer, but folowing solution doesn't work on real db( I undestend your idea , and i will try to implement it. 
Can i add sort and group functions in that query for another groups from db?